# CSS and Script Links no longer work after moving to local IIS

Tags: jquery, css, asp.net-mvc, iis, configuration

I know this has been posted before, as I have googled the snot out of this problem and I cannot find a resolution.

I have a site that loads fine when it was in a Visual Studio Deployment server.  CSS loaded, JQuery Scripts loaded, and the connection to the database was functional.

I have since moved it to my local IIS Server (Windows 7 Pro machine) and I'm having all sorts of issues that I know are related to how my links are setup and how IIS is reading them.

None of my links to scripts or Css work anymore:

```
<link href="/Content/CSS/Layout.css" rel="stylesheet"  type="text/css"/>
@*<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-2.1.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.11.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>*@
<script src='@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.1.11.1.js")'></script>
```

As you can see by the commented lines, I've tried different ways of writing them.  If I set my JQuery source to Google Hosted Libraries, the scripts run.  But the catch is that any jquery function that uses AJAx to call a controller, I get a 404 error now.

```
$(".rdoSelectTicket").on('click', function () {
        var value = $(this).val();
        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("SelectTicketView", "HelpDesk")',
            data: { 'ticketID': value },
            type: 'GET',
            success: function (data) {
                $("#loadpartial").html(data);
                }
        });
    });
```

I've set the permissions on the folder that hosts my website to Full Control for everyone just to rule out a permissions thing.

I have installed Static Content under Common HTTP Features and that doesn't help.[image: IIS Install]

I've also made sure that StaticFile Handlermappings was correct:

[image: Static handling]

When I use the IE Develper Tools it tells me my CSS was ignored due to mime mismatch and that it failed to open [mycomputer]/content/css/layout.css.  That is the correct path to my CSS.

Everything loads on the inital page (minus any styling).  It makes the connection to the database and pulls the needed data.  But if I click a link I get the 404 error.

I am clueless at this point as to what needs to be done.  Like I said, I know this has been posted before but everything I tried from the other posts has not worked.

All the navigation issues have been resolved by pointing to google API library for Jquery.

The only issue remaining is the fact that CSS still does not load at all.

UPDATE:  I've completely reformatted my computer.  Reinstalled IIS and VS 2010.  The problem still occurs.  Even if I create the default application within VS.  When I create a view that is linked to the existing Css style sheet that vs created, the css does not load.  I get the same errors as within my application.

Comment: Maybe the path is wrong. Try adding local path.

Comment: Did you try the dev tools in chrome, IE or Fiddler to see the request path for your CSS and JQuery links?

Comment: When I use the Developer tools for IE the debugger tells me Failed to open http://localhost/Content/CSS/Layout.css.  Which is the correct path.

Comment: Is your site in a Virtual Folder or at the root ?  Why arent you using the @Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/jquery.min.js") ..i guess your @Url.Content() should have worked :(

Comment: I've tried it at both and it didn't help unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

Chances are your pathing for your CSS and JS needs to be adjusted.  You are not using pathing relative to the site.

I would also consider using a CDN for your jQuery stuff.

Comment: I've tried it different ways with no avail.  "../Content/CSS/Layout.CSS" doesn't work either.  My understanding is that using @Url.Action is the preferred way which doesn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

try this instead of actual css path

@Href('~/css_path')

In ASP.NET you can set path with @Href mvc helper

Comment: That didn't work either.  It's definitely something in IIS.  I've I created a default MVC 4 application and just ran it.  It runs, but with none of the css loaded.  I added a simple controller and view.  I edited the CSS sheet that's already created and linked to the layout view and it still giving me the error.